# How do I print "Hello, World!" 100 times in Go?

Tags: go

I have this so far, but I'm not sure what to add to make it print "Hello, World!" 100 times... How can I do it?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, World!")
}
```

Comment: Seriously! I mean freaking seriously!

Comment: Simple question with a simple answer. I do not see any problem :(...

Comment: @Alfred: The problem is that anyone who has put forth any effort into learning the language will be able to do this. The *"I have this so far"* code is basically just a copy/paste of the code from the http://golang.org/ homepage. Though StackOverflow more and more is becoming a magnet for people who won't try for themselves... so I guess it doesn't surprise me that some people like you don't find this to be a problem.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. Also, here is the obligatory ["What have you tried?"](http://whathaveyoutried.com/).

Comment: Well, here is my obvious solution: https://gist.github.com/DavidEGrayson/c43987a3ba717c50344d

Answer (score 4):

That would be something like (assuming the other code is correct):

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        fmt.Println("Hello world")
    }
}
```

Comment: does this go on the first line outside the first { ?

Comment: @user2038261, added context to make it clearer.

Answer (score 4):

You should definitely use *[strings.Repeat](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Repeat)*:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Print(strings.Repeat("Hello, World!\n", 100))
}
```